# Achieve fine grain widths with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With bootstrap, I fine the col widths are not quite subtle enough in some cases. Here's a really nice template I'm trying to emulate for learning purposes:

[image: their attempt]

Now, here's my attempt:

[image: my attempt]

It's in an early stage, but already these widths aren't really working for me. The gap between the two buttons is far too wide and clunky for my liking.

```
<div class="mobile-menu btn-group col-xs-12">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle col-xs-12" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Large button <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-6">
        <li> Item One </li>
        <li> Item Two </li>
        <li> Item Three </li>
        <li> Item Four </li>
        <li> Item Five </li>
    </ul>
</div>



<div class = 'col-xs-6'>
    <a class = 'btn btn-primary col-xs-12'> Make a Donation </a>
</div>

<div class = 'col-xs-6'>
    <a class = 'btn btn-primary col-xs-12'> Make a Donation </a>
</div>
```

How can I achieve a finer grain of control? I've attempted nesting the buttons as you can see, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak almost anything you like here.  Add more columns, less space between the columns etc.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

As MightySchmoePong pointed out, you can customize and download it. And I also found firefox Developer tool/console and alike to be indispensable tool to achieve a finer grain of control in bootstrap usage. Once you identify the specific element you are intersected in with the help of the Developer tool, you can easily target this element to your requirement by writing a custom LESS or CSS for it.